# Конфигурация интернационализации Thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, properties

Не могу настроить чтение свойств из файла `*.properties`, используя Thymeleaf:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org/">
    <head>
    <title>Good Thymes Virtual Grocery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"
          href="../css/main-style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p th:text="#{index.welcome}"></p>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Сами файлы свойств:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И содержимое одного из них для примера:

```
index.welcome = Привет!
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте бин

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
</bean>
```

Как его использовать и далее по тексту примеры можно найти в [примере](https://devcolibri.com/spring-3-mvc-internationalization-and-localization/) на тему интернационализации.

> Настройка интернационализации (i18n) / локализации (l10n) в Spring MVC
>
> Мы создали resource properties для нашего приложения. Теперь мы должны
>   объявить эти файлы в конфигурационом файле spring `*-servlet.xml`.
>
> Будем использовать класс
>   `org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`
>   для определения resource properties.
>
> ```
> <bean id="messageSource"
>     class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
>     <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
>     <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
> </bean>
> ```