# Spring интернационалировать данные из БД

Tags: java, spring, mvc, jpa

Я не знаю как мне правильно интернационалировать данные из БД.
У меня есть веб-приложение Spring. Все переводы текста на страницах я записываю в пакет в виде ключ:значение(фото 1)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же у меня есть сущность "Product", которая хранится в БД и имеет поле "описание". Это поле так же должно быть переведено, но если текст на сайте пишется заранее, то товар добавляется при включенном приложении через интерфейс.
Как правильно реализовать интернационализацию этого поля?

Comment: Очевидно нужно хранить поле для каждого варианта перевода. Если список фиксированный, то это может быть просто три поля в одной сущности. Если список языков нефиксированный или полей для интернационализации много, то можно их хранить в отдельной таблице `i18n_texts(id, lang, text)`, а в сущности ссылку на id.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Конфигурация интернационализации Thymeleaf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/861634/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-thymeleaf)