# Spring MVC ResourceBundle не могу найти путь к файлам локализации

Tags: java, spring

я пытаюсь создать ENUM класс с интернационализацией.
У меня есть набор из 3 языков, который хранится по пути "\src\main\resources",

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а так же сам enum:

```
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public enum PaymentMethod {
    MINIMUM_PREPAYMENT, FULL_PAYMENT;

    private static final ResourceBundle res =
            ResourceBundle.getBundle("Messages");

    public String toString() {
        return res.getString(name() + ".paymentMethod");
    }
}
```

Но при попытке сменить язык, текст не переводится, то есть при обращении по пути ".getBundle("Messages");" получаю только один файл перевода, как получить их все?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В различных примерах видел "getBundle("com.example.Messages");", но у меня набор хранится в папке ресурсов. Так же необходимо решение, которы бы работало из jar файла.

Comment: С помощью `getBundle()` ничего не подгрузишь. Нужно чтобы он грузился автоматически, например как в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/861868/204920) ответе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В javadoc метода `ResourceBundle#getBundle(String baseName)` написано, что загружается ресурс с дефолтной Locale.

То есть, если вам нужен файл с русской локалицазией, вам следует загружать файл таким образом:

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages", Locale.forLanguageTag("ru"));
```

Comment: Так же советую использовать `MessageSource` бин, если у вас spring-boot приложение. Этот класс автоматически подгрузит все необходимые ресурсы (надо будет указать имя bundle в проперти `spring.messages.basename`.